# How to set the JSTL variable value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

How to set the JSTL variable value in java script?

```
<script>

 function function1()

 { 

  var val1 = document.getElementById('userName').value;

  <c:set var="user" value=""/>  // how do i set val1 here?   

 }
 </script>
```

How do I set the '**user**' variable (*JSTL*) value from '**val1**' (*Java script*)?

Answer (score 52):

It is not possible because they are executed in different environments (JSP at server side, JavaScript at client side). So they are not executed in the sequence you see in your code.

```
var val1 = document.getElementById('userName').value; 

<c:set var="user" value=""/>  // how do i set val1 here?
```

Here JSTL code is executed at server side and the server sees the JavaScript/Html codes as simple texts. The generated contents from JSTL code (if any) will be rendered in the resulting HTML along with your other JavaScript/HTML codes. Now the browser renders HTML along with executing the Javascript codes. Now remember there is no JSTL code available for the browser.

Now for example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<c:set var="message" value="Hello"/> 
var message = '<c:out value="${message}"/>';
</script>
```

Now for the browser, this content is rendered,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var message = 'Hello';
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How do i set the value outside the script tag. Example 

The following snippet are outside the <script> tag.

<input type="hidden" name="userName" value="Administrator"/>
<c:set var="user" value=""/>  // how do i set hidden variable value here (user variable)?

Comment: The 'user' variable is a scoped attribute at server side and the input element is available at client side. To update something in server, you need to post the data to server through form submission. If you want to display some data from the server, you can do it as part of generating the response content as in my example. Moreover it doesn't matter for the container to execute a JSTL whether it is inside a script tag or not because it just parses the JSTL, executes and renders the resulting response(if any) from tag; It renders other texts(HTML/JavaScript) as it is.

Comment: Sorry! I don't remember clicking on the downvote button, but apparently I did so. Unfortunately at this point I can't undo the vote unless the answer is modified. Again, sorry!

Answer (score 13):

one more approach to use.

first, define the following somewhere on the page:

```
<div id="valueHolderId">${someValue}</div>
```

then in JS, just do something similar to

```
var someValue = $('#valueHolderId').html();
```

it works great for the cases when all scripts are inside .js files and obviously there is no jstl available

Answer (score 6):

```
<script ...
  function(){
   var someJsVar = "<c:out value='${someJstLVarFromBackend}'/>";

  }
</script>
```

This **works even if** you dont have a hidden/non-hidden input field set somewhere in the jsp.

Answer (score 2):

Just don't. Don't write code with code. Write a JSON object or a var somewhere but for the love of a sensible HTTP divide, don't write JavaScript functions or methods hardcoded with vars/properties provided by JSTL. Generating JSON is cool. It ends there or your UI dev hates you.

Imagine if you had to dig into JavaScript to find something that was setting parameters in the middle of a class that originated on the client-side. It's awful. Pass data back and forth. Handle the data. But don't try to generate actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the normal string concatenation but you have to make sure the value is a Valid XML string, you will find a good practice to write XML in this source http://oreilly.com/pub/h/2127, or if you like you can use an API in javascript to write XML as [helma](http://helma.serverjs.org/reference/jala.XmlWriter.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

This variable can be set using `value="${val1}"` inside `c:set` if you have used jquery in your system.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer I say No. You can only get values from jstl to javascript. But u can display the user name using javascript itself.
Best ways are here.
To display user name,
if u have html like

```
<div id="uName"></div>
```

You can display user name as follows.

```
var val1 = document.getElementById('userName').value;
document.getElementById('uName').innerHTML = val1;
```

#### To get data from jstl to your javascript :

```
var userName = '<c:out value="${user}"/>';
```

here ${user} is the data you get as response(from backend).

#### Asigning number/array length

```
var arrayLength = <c:out value="${details.size()}"/>;
```

#### Advanced

```
function advanced(){
    var values = new Array();
    <c:if test="${empty details.users}">
       values.push("No user found"); 
    </c:if>         

    <c:if test="${!empty details.users}">
        <c:forEach var="user" items="${details.users}" varStatus="stat">
            values.push("${user.name}");   
        </c:forEach>
    </:c:if>
    alert("values[0] "+values[0]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the whole jstl object as a Javascript object by converting the whole object to json. It is possible by **Jackson** in java.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class JsonUtil{
   public static String toJsonString(Object obj){
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = ...; // jackson object mapper
      return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
   }
}
```

### /WEB-INF/tags/util-functions.tld:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd" 
  version="2.1"> 

  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <uri>http://www.your.url/util-functions</uri>

  <function>
      <name>toJsonString</name>
      <function-class>your.package.JsonUtil</function-class>
      <function-signature>java.lang.String toJsonString(java.lang.Object)</function-signature>
  </function>  

</taglib>
```

### web.xml

```
<jsp-config>
  <tablib>
    <taglib-uri>http://www.your.url/util-functions</taglib-uri>
    <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/tags/util-functions.tld</taglib-location>
  </taglib>
</jsp-confi>
```

### mypage.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="uf" uri="http://www.your.url/util-functions" %> 

<script>
   var myJavaScriptObject = JSON.parse('${uf:toJsonString(myJstlObject)}');
</script>
```