# Set variable JSTL within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jstl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set the JSTL variable value in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287114/how-to-set-the-jstl-variable-value-in-javascript)

I have certain codes as following:

```
    <c:set var="test" scope="page" value="0"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var time;

    function Check(){
       if(time <= 0)
       {
           <c:set var="test" scope="page" value="1"/>         
       }
      time-=1;
    }
    </script>
```

when I did

```
      <c:out value="${test}"/>
```

it seems that its value's always 1 and it happened before time=0 or less than 0. And also did something below:

```
      <c:if test="${test=='1'}">
        <sql:transaction dataSource="${dataBase}">
          <sql:update var="tDel">
               DELETE FROM tmp_time WHERE username='${username}'
          </sql:update>
        </sql:transaction>
     </c:if>
```

It always comes to DELETE at the first time and not wait till time=0 or less.
Can anyone help me out?

Comment: @ArtemKoshelev:Perhaps, but it's not the same. CMIIW

Comment: All of the server-side code executes on the server _before_ the browser sees it. So JavaScript can't set a JSTL variable value at all. If you want a client-side countdown in JS before a server-side operation such as a database deletion you will need to make an Ajax request when the time is up. Note that `time-=;` is a syntax error, and given that you don't initialise `time` when you then test it with `if(time <= 0)` that condition will always be false.

Comment: @nnnnnn:Sorry, i just edited my codes.

Comment: P.S. If you use your browser's View Page Source option you'll see why the above code didn't work to try to access JSTL stuff from JS.