# JSTL in javascript (get list of jbean)

Tags: javascript, jsp, jstl

I'm developing a shortned url project . And I would use a javascript function to display a pie diagram .
I want to know if it's possible to pass a list of Javabean (jst , jsp ) to a javascript function ( array , table..) ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287114/how-to-set-the-jstl-variable-value-in-javascript

Comment: hi ,
the probleme with this solution : we can use only a simple varibale (String) . In my case , I want to get a List of javabean sent by a servlet to the jsp page and create an array in javascript to store my List and do some actions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One efficient way to achieve this is to create a [JSON](http://json.org/) structure on server side and pass it on to the client side.  I suppose your chart data will be in an array or tabular format.

There are various JSON libraries available like Jackson. [Refer to Jackson example.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/)

Once you have constructed appropriate JSON object on Server side, you can refer to it on JSP by assigning the value in one line call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonObj = '<c:out value="${jsonObject}"/>';
// you can refer to jsonObj in rest of the script 
// including external JavaScript file
</script>
```

In above example jsonObject is constructed on server side in Servlet or controller etc.