# Is it a good practice to use JSTL inside a script (javascript) tag?

Tags: java, javascript, jstl

I'm developing a web app using JSTL and Javascript in Eclipse Juno. I've been reading questions like [How to set the JSTL variable value in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287114/how-to-set-the-jstl-variable-value-in-javascript) and my code works good even if I have error in eclipse:

[image]

But... Is it a good practice to use JSTL and Javascript like this?

Does it cause a low performance in the time of rendering the webpage?

Can this be done in other way?

Comment: JSTL = server side. Javascript = client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it a good practice to use JSTL and Javascript like this?

It is not bad practice or good practice. The bad practice would be using JSTL to control the flow of JavaScript, which is **plain wrong** because JSTL runs on server side and JavaScript on client side.

> Does it cause a low performance in the time of rendering the webpage?

JSTL will only help to generate the HTML for the current view. JavaScript is not involved in the HTML generation at server side but at client side unless you work with nodejs or similar technologies.

> Can this be done in other way?

This depends on what you're doing. Common way to access to data when accessing to a web page:

1. Application Server (AS) receives a GET request on `http://www.foo.com/bar`
2. AS pre process the GET request (load data from database or another data source, pre calculations, etc)
3. AS creates the response for the GET request (apply the data to generate the HTML)
4. AS sends the response to the client.
5. The browser client renders the HTML.

Another way to do it:

1. Application Server (AS) receives a GET request on `http://www.foo.com/bar`
2. AS creates the response for the GET request (generate the HTML which contains JavaScript functions to load the data in the `onload` event).
3. AS sends the response to the client.
4. The browser client renders the HTML.
5. The `onload` event fires and load data in the `onload` event through RESTful services. This way, the data interaction is handled in client side only, but the data comes from server side.

These are two very simple alternatives to handle the same problem. Which one to choose and work with will depend entirely on your design, there's no definitive answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Luiggi Mendoza. In my question I added an image with my code. I'm using a <c:if> tag to determine whether a change handler is added to the code or not. Can that be called control the flow? Am I doing a bad practice in that chunk of code?

Comment: @Jessai yes, that's bad practice, as noted in my answer (that's why I posted that part of the text =] ). And for future questions, do not provide an image of your code, instead provide your current code. No te  preocupes si no lo sabes formatear, alguien te ayudara un par de veces y aprendes.

Comment: Can you give a clue or a link where I can check how to change my code and avoid the bad practice ?

Comment: @Jessai I don't know about such link. I can tell you that you should move the data to server side or to client side, then do the necessary processing. In the case you posted, seems that you need to move the data from `${param.pedimentoId}` to JavaScript, then perform the validations in JavaScript.