# Set a value in JSP passed from javascript to a modal for JSTL

Tags: javascript, jsp, modal-dialog, jstl

I have this javascript defining what happens when a user clicks on a button:

```
   $(document).on("click", ".open-ViewResultsModal", function () {
       var versionNumber = $(this).data('id');
       $(".modal-body #versionNumber").val(versionNumber);
       $('#viewResultsModal').modal('show');
   });
```

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="versionNumber" name="versionNumber" value="work plz"/>
```

This works fine in that the versionNumber input I have defined in my modal gets the correct value. However, I don't know how to use that to do the JSTL logic I have to do:

```
  <c:forEach var="result" items="${array[<versionNumber>]}">
 ...
  </c:forEach>
```

I have been trying and failing to somehow get the value of the input into that  variable I'm using in my for loop. I read about using the implicit param variable to pass this kind of information, but I don't know how that is done in this context.

Comment: you can set it with C:set to a variable and then you can use.

Comment: @SemihEker What would the syntax be for the value in the c:set?

Comment: I saw an example to set value in js in this question. I hope it helps you; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287114/how-to-set-the-jstl-variable-value-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you pass this datum with request to the JSP then this request parameter can be read using the EL syntax ${param.your_parameter_name}

Comment: I don't have the slightest idea what this means. What does it mean to "pass this datum with request to the JSP"? I specified in my question that I didn't know how to do this exact thing.

Comment: i mean passing request as follows: your_page.jsp?your_param=param_value